# Deploy AWS lambda with cross account S3 code source without a bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to deploy a lambda function in account A with a zip file from S3 bucket in account B. The problem is that the S3 public access is disabled for account B. Is it possible to get this done without using an S3 bucket policy.

I tried the below cross account IAM setup and it does not work.

Account B IAM role:

S3 access inline policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1608150488840",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::the-code-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Trust policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "<Account-A-Id>"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

A pre-signed S3 URL of the source code zip file also gave access denied error in lambda.

Comment: " it possible to get this done without using an S3 bucket policy" no, it is not.  All cross account access must be done with a resource policy.  In this case that's the S3 bucket policy.